# Prometheus alerting rule not detecting first time metric increase

Tags: prometheus

I have one counter metric `error_in_execution`. Whenever the error appears `counter.inc();` called.
I have the following alert expression that triggers when the counter increase.

```
expr: increase(error_in_execution[5m]) > 0
for: 5m
```

Now the issue is, when there is no metric exists and an error appear the first time, the counter value increase to 1. Which is not detected by this alert expression and it did not trigger. Then when the counter increases to 2. Alert triggered.

The following example would be easy to understand.

```
Time 0: 
Prometheus: error_in_execution --> No Metric Exsist. 
Alert: increase(error_in_execution[5m]) > 0 --> Not triggered 

Time 1: Error occur [error_in_execution.inc()]
Prometheus: error_in_execution --> 1
Alert: increase(error_in_execution[5m]) > 0 --> Still Not triggered <<<<<< It should be triggered. ( Please help here) 

Time 2: Error occur [error_in_execution.inc()]
Prometheus: error_in_execution --> 2
Alert: increase(error_in_execution[5m]) > 0 --> Alert triggerd.
```

Answer (score 3):

I think I found a workaround for this.

For counters that existed before t, `increase(_metric_[t])` is equivalent to `_metric_ - _metric_ offset t`. (it's not, but that is a different issue).
For counters that did not exist before t, the increase is simply the metrics value `_metric_ - 0 = _metric_`.

We can find out whether a metric existed at point t by querying it `_metric_ offset t`. And we can use that as a `WHERE NOT EXISTS` filter using the `unless` operator.

Putting it together, we get following query:

```
( _metric_ unless _metric offset 1d ) or ( _metric_ - _metric_ offset 1d )
^-----------new counters------------^    ^--------existing counters------^
```

##### Example

One event happens each timeframe, we want to measure the increase over 2 timeframes.
Expected:
- none for each query frame before the first occurrence
- one for the query frame on first occurrence
- 2 for each query frame beyond the first occurrence

```
                               t0  t1  t2  t3  t4  t5
_metric_                       -   -   1   2   3   4
_metric offset 2t              -   -   -   -   1   2
__ unless __ offset 2t         -   -   1   2   -   -
__ <minus> __ offset 2t        -   -   -   -   2   2
=====================================================
() or ()                       -   -   1   2   2   2
```

[Grafana example graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBOR8.png)
`total` is the raw counter value, `increase` is the result of the query. It is still split in two series because the metric name is dropped on the `-` operation, but not on `unless`. But summing them up again works well, and is something you will probably do anyways.
[Grafana graph with sum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qmlzk.png)

It's really a shame prometheus makes it so hard for everyone who does not use it to display cpu temperature. This is one of the instances where my pride to have found a solution is only surpassed by my exasperation that it was necessary in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

This is a "normal" behaviour. If the metric does not exist before and is then initialized with the value `1`, this is not considered in functions like `increase()` or `rate()`.

To catch the very first error, you need to make sure, that the metric exists from the beginning when your application starts having the initial value `0`, then the first incrementatation will trigger your alert.

Comment: Hi Jens, the metric will be different for lable = AccountId. Moreover whenever we deploy a new version of the service we delete all the metric. Because it is not more required. 
Can't we somehow achieve it with expression?

Comment: do I understand it correctly that you have a label "accountid"? whats the cardinality of accounfIds in your system? if it is a low number, you could create one counter for each accountid at the start of your application, if it is a bigger number its a bad Ided to have a counter for every one, as prometheus creats files for each uniique label value combination and that might overload your system.